# Hide certain search results using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a basic search bar with about 25 options to be searched, what I need to do is hide 2 of those options from the user. Initially, the modal with the options loads like this:

[image: Init]

But if i write and delete something in the input this is what happens:

[image: Example]

I need to hide the repeated option `CÓDIGO` and the blank one from the user, (just like the first image) but I'm having trouble doing so...

Here is the JQuery code used to perform the search:

```
 $('#searchColumns').on('keyup', function () {
    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $('#selectColumnsTable tr').filter(function() {
       $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1);
    });
 });
```

And just in case, the code for the modal: (using Alpine.js [v2.8.2](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/tree/v2.8.2) and laravel-livewire)

```
<div x-data="{
        data:columns,
        selectedColumns: ['sap_id'],
    }" 
    wire:ignore class="modal fade" id="selectColumnsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Selecionar Colunas</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <i aria-hidden="true" class="ki ki-close"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <p class="mx-10 mt-4">Selecione até 9 colunas para exibir...</p>
                <div class="text-center mx-10">
                    <div class="input-icon">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome da coluna..." id="searchColumns">
                        <span>
                            <i class="flaticon2-search-1 text-muted"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mt-6 text-center">
                        <table id="selectColumnsTable" class="table table-hover gy-5">
                            <thead>
                                <th class="text-left">
                                    Coluna
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-left">
                                    <i class="la la-eye"></i>
                                </th>
                            <thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-left ml-4"> 
                                        <span x-html="columns[1].title"></span> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-left">
                                        <input 
                                            x-model="selectedColumns"
                                            class="sapId" 
                                            id="sapId"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            value="sap_id" 
                                            disabled 
                                            checked
                                        >
                                    </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <template x-for="(column, index) in data" :key="index">                          
                                    <tr x-show="column.field != 'id' && column.field != 'sap_id' &&column.title != '' && column.title != 'CÓDIGO'">
                                        <td class="text-left ml-4"> 
                                            <span x-html="column.title"></span> 
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-left">
                                            <input 
                                                x-model="selectedColumns" 
                                                id="selectColumns" 
                                                class="selectColumns" 
                                                type="checkbox" 
                                                :value=column.field
                                            >
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </template>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <button @click="displaySelected(selectedColumns)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-5" data-target="click">Exibir selecionadas</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-5" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you're using both Livewire and Alpine, why would you even want to perform the search using JQuery???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know livewire or alpine, but it seems that jquery is showing what alpine hid.

See if this works for you, I tried to make a similar html structure, with the 2 lines starting hidden, and skip these 2 lines when searching the others:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <style>
      .hidden {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <input type="text" id="searchColumns" />

  <table id="selectColumnsTable">
    <tr>
      <td><span>CÓDIGO</span></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked="true" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td><span>CÓDIGO</span></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td><span></span></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>RAZÃO SOCIAL</span></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>INT VISITA</span></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>INT COMPRA</span></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>ATENDIMENTO</span></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>SAC</span></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>INT COMPRA</span></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    $("#searchColumns").on("keyup", function () {
      var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

      $("#selectColumnsTable tr").filter(function () {
        let linhaCodigo = $(this).find("span").html() === "CÓDIGO";
        let linhaId = $(this).find("span").html() === "";

        if (!linhaCodigo && !linhaId)
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1);
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```